# Can't add a connection in Visual Studio: no server name available

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, windows-10

I am trying to add a new data connection in Visual Studio. In the Server Name list, I have nothing.
I installed Visual Studio Community and SQL Server Express 2014.
I enabled Shared Memory, Named Pipes and TCP/IP.
In Visual Studio, I can see a server named 'WINDOWS-ORUALD2' under server in the Server Explorer.
In the services, I can see that SQL Server SQL Express is running. I also added port 1433 in the firewall exception and even tried turning off the firewall wall for a moment.

Finally when trying to add the connection, I get the following error:
A network related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection. Server not found or not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Is sql express installed as default instance, or SQLEXPRESS named instance? Did you try WINDOWS-ORUALD2\SQLEXPRESS as server name?

Comment: WINDOWS-ORUALD2\SQLEXPRESS as a server name worked. I believe SQL EXPRESS was installed as a default instance.